# Changed a navigation point in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress for the first time (I know how to code) and I am having issues trying to figure out its software. The developer before me didn't make pages. He made Posts and assigned them to different categories. What I did was went into the pages tab and added a page called Events. When I did this I changed the link point to it to be `/events`. Well now every link on the site (at least home page) goes to `/events` even though I deleted the page.

When you click on Learn More within the Nutcracker news article (on home page, under slider). I want it to go to the news page (or in this case news post within the news navigation page).

Please let me know if you need any sort of code or other pictures.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Picture]
[image]

Comment: I'd check in appearance>theme options and see if there's some default setting there. I can't see the elegant theme documentation w/o joining.

Comment: @TomWoodward I do not see anything in that menu that would help. It is the buttons in a post that are going to the events page (which I deleted). I posted a new pic in my question.

Comment: not knowing how deep you went in there, general settings looks more like where this might be, layout is another option (which might have additional page options). GodWords is  right, but more links can be set via theme options. You might also just update the permalinks and see if that clears things (Settings>permalinks). No need to change anything.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that out in a second. Is it common to create posts instead of pages or did this person have no idea what they were doing.

Comment: In my experience, categories would be common for News (other repeating/serial/ephemeral types of content) but a strange choice for a single mission statement.

Comment: this might be useful if the more link has been customized by the theme or the previous webdev https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: Well the link was fine before I added the events page. Eventually I want it to go to the events page, but now I just want it to go to was it was originally.

Comment: Even the Mission post (right under the nutcracker) goes to /events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124681/discussion-between-tom-woodward-and-becky).

Answer (score 1):

"More" links are programmatic. The More button in the editor makes this:

<!--more-->

...and WordPress creates the right link on the fly. Clearly, WP thinks the links should go to Events. Edit the page and look right below the page title for the Permalink. This can be changed without affecting the page title, and vice versa. Does the Permalink say Events? If so, change it to the real destination.

Links you manually add to your content must be manually edited.

Comment: I deleted the events page though and it is still going to it? 

The previous developer did not create pages. He just made posts, so I am not sure how to get to the "Learn More".

Comment: You don't need to 'get to' the More button. It works automatically...WP sees the code <!--more--> and says, "get the post id, then make a link that goes there."

Check your trash. The deleted page is still there, so the link may still be looking for it. That's a quirk of WordPress and databases...until the Trash is emptied, you can't name another page with the same name because it still exists. If you delete the page from the Trash, it may fix the issue. 

Make sure to Edit the post and check the Permalink, right below the Title. THAT is likely where the issue lies.

Comment: I deleted the page from the trash...forgot to check the permalink for the title before I did it though, but the same issue is going on now, unless my cache is not updating.

Comment: Even the Mission post (right under the nutcracker) goes to /events.